# send hex variable via TCP socket

Tags: lua

Probably it's an easy thing, but I'm a Lua beginner... 
I'm creating a very simple QSC QSYS plugin to control a projection server using KVL API. Server API is based on hex strings. 
For example this command asks the server to load a the playlist with `9bf5455689ed4c019731c6dd3c071f0e` uuid:

```
Controls["LoadSPL"].EventHandler = function()
    sock:Write(
        "\x06\x0e\x2b\x34\x02\x05\x01\x0a\x0e\x10\x01\x01\x01\x03\x09\x00\x83\x00\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00\x01\x9b\xf5\x45\x56\x89\xed\x4c\x01\x97\x31\xc6\xdd\x3c\x07\x1f\x0e"
    )
end
```

Now I need to be able to create a string with a variable UUID, according to the text indicated in a textbox (or a list of available UUIDs read from the server) in the user interface.
I will concatenate this string to the fixed part of the command.
How can I correctly make a string like 
`ad17fc696b49454db17d593db3e553e5` become 
`\xad\x17\xfc\x69\x6b\x49\x45\x4d\xb1\x7d\x59\x3d\xb3\xe5\x53\xe5`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
local input = "ad17fc696b49454db17d593db3e553e5"
local output = input:gsub("%w%w", function(s) return string.char(tonumber(s, 16)) end)
```

Explanation: this takes every pair of characters, interprets them as base 16 numeric string, and then takes the character with that number, and uses that to replace the original characters.

---

EDIT: To make it clear what's going on, and why the other answers are wrong, backslash escape sequences like `\xad` are a feature of the Lua source code, in memory it's represented by a byte with value `173`, just like `A` is represented by a byte with value `65`. Trying to concatenate a literal backslash character with hexadecimal characters does not create an escape code. So the way to do that is manually with `string.char`.

Comment: Their answers weren't correct, they produce the string `"\\xad\\x17\\xfc\\x69\\x6b\\x49\\x45\\x4d\\xb1\\x7d\\x59\\x3d\\xb3\\xe5\\x53\\xe5"`. OP writes in a comment "the second part is sent with "\x" as part of the text itself". I downvoted the answers because I knew they were incorrect. I also take issue with the "90% of their code" claim, as the only part I took over was the input (which was part of the question), the variable names (which are inconsequential), and the replacement patter (which is trivial).

Answer (score -1):

```
#! /usr/bin/env lua

str = 'ad17fc696b49454db17d593db3e553e5'
strx = ''

for i = 1, #str, 2 do  --  loop through every-other position in your string
    chars = str :sub( i, i+1 )  --  capture every 2 chars
    strx = strx ..'\\x' ..chars
end  --  append a literal backslash, the letter x, then those 2 chars

target = [[\xad\x17\xfc\x69\x6b\x49\x45\x4d\xb1\x7d\x59\x3d\xb3\xe5\x53\xe5]]
print( x, x == target )  --  print results, and test if it meets expected target
```

> \xad\x17\xfc\x69\x6b\x49\x45\x4d\xb1\x7d\x59\x3d\xb3\xe5\x53\xe5    true

This can be code-golfed into a one-liner

```
x=''for i=1,#s,2 do x=x..'\\x'..s:sub(i,i+1)end
```

Comment: Thanks. 
The code creates the right string. However, when I try to concatenate it to the first part of the code 
"\x06\x0e\x2b\x34\x02\x05\x01\x0a\x0e\x10\x01\x01\x01\x03\x03\x00\x83\x00\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00\x01"
the result is that the first part is correctly sent as hex via socket, but the second part is sent with "\x" as part of the text itself

Comment: @EliaO I can't make sense of that comment. please add that information to your question providing an example